# Glide Library Loading Very Slow with GIF

Tags: java, firebase, android-glide

I'm using Glide library to load GIF files into my app. Here is what I implemented:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(stringImage)
     .asGif()
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
     .into(postImage);
```

But for some reason the GIF files are loading with very slow frame. I tried to Google but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73607117/7558125

Checkout my answer

Answer (score 2):

Adding crossfade on local image drawable worked for me.

```
Glide.with(context).load(stringImage).asGif()
   .crossFade().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(postImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it worked for me too...

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load(sticker.getImageUrl())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
                        .crossFade().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                        .into(imgView);
```