# Error:(35, 24) error: cannot find symbol method crossFade() in latest Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I have an old project using Glide 3.5.2. The below works fine.

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .override(IMAGE_SIZE_FIX, IMAGE_SIZE_FIX)
            .crossFade()
            .placeholder(placeholder)
            .into(imageView);
```

However, now I update my Glide to 4.5.0. It complains

```
Error:(35, 24) error: cannot find symbol method override(int,int)
```

I tried answer from 
[Glide-4.0.0 Missing placeholder, error, GlideApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481756/glide-4-0-0-missing-placeholder-error-glideapp) that solve the `overide(int,int)` issue. But then the `crossfade()` becomes issue.

The ways I tried as below...

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(IMAGE_SIZE_FIX, IMAGE_SIZE_FIX).placeholder(placeholder))
            .crossFade()
            .into(imageView);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(IMAGE_SIZE_FIX, IMAGE_SIZE_FIX).placeholder(placeholder).crossFade())
            .into(imageView);
```

Both doesn't work. complaining

```
Error:(51, 17) error: cannot find symbol method crossFade()
```

How could I apply `.crossFade()`?

Answer (score 5):

**`FYI`** latest `dependencies` is

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
```

> **EDIT**

[**`Cross fades`**](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#cross-fades)

Unlike **`Glide v3`**, **`Glide v4`** does NOT apply a cross fade or any other transition by default to requests. Transitions must be applied manually.

To apply a cross fade transition to a particular load, you can use:

```
import static com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade;

Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CChZ.jpg?s=328&g=1")
            .transition(withCrossFade())
            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(100, 100)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).centerCrop()
            )
            .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 3):

To apply a cross fade transition to a particular load, you can use:

```
import static com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade;

Glide.with(fragment)
      .load(url)
      .transition(withCrossFade())
      .into(imageView);
```

**Or:**

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .transition(
      new DrawableTransitionOptions
        .crossFade())
  .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion It's Is Best

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .transition(
      new DrawableTransitionOptions
        .crossFade())
  .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue with current version of Glide. But later found that if we dont provide the imageview with proper width/height that is if we leave it wrap_content then no matter how fast is your gif it will render very slowly.

Provide fixed width like match_parent or "0dp" and that will do the magic